# How does the compiler choose which method to call when a parameter type is ambiguous?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I have the following code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        Foo(null);
    }

    private void Foo (object bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo - object");
    }

    private void Foo (string bar)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo - string");
    }
```

and when I run the test "TestFoo()", the console output is "Foo - string". How does the compiler decide which method to call?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It applies the "better conversion" rules (7.4.3.3 of the C# 3 spec) as part of overload resolution (section 7.4.3 in general).

Basically in this case there's a conversion from `string` to `object`, but not from `object` to `string`. Following the rules, that means the conversion from `null` to `string` is better than the one from `null` to `object`, so the overload with the `string` parameter is used.

Overload resolution can get extremely complicated when the following factors get involved:

- There could be generic methods in the candidate set
- If there *are* generic methods, type inference is applied to each of them separately, giving different conversion opportunities
- If any arguments are method groups, they could be converted to different delegate types - possibly even using different method signatures if the named method group *also* has multiple overloads
- Inheritance can lead to surprising results
- Parameter arrays (`params`) add to the fun
- Optional parameters in C# 4 contribute to the decision too

Basically overloading can be a real can of worms - where possible, design overloads so that only one of them will ever be a valid target of any given method call, so that you don't need to worry about the detailed rules.