# How does C# resolve overloaded constructors: Foo(Exception) and Foo(object)?

Tags: c#, .net

When having a function Foo(object) and an overload Foo(Exception), calls to Foo(null) are evaluated by Foo(Exception). Why is this?

UPDATE: (so basically most but not all nulls gets resolved to Foo(Exception))

Exception e = new Exception();

e = null;
Foo bar = new Foo(e);              //Evaulated by Foo(Exception)
Foo bar = new Foo((object)e);      //Evaluated by Foo(object)

object o = null;
Foo bar = new Foo(o);   //Evaluated by Foo(object)
Foo bar = new Foo(null);           //Evaulated by Foo(Exception)
Foo bar = new Foo((object)null);           //Evaulated by Foo(object)

Thanks everyone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the compiler choose which method to call when a parameter type is ambiguous?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696660/how-does-the-compiler-choose-which-method-to-call-when-a-parameter-type-is-ambigu)

Comment: Additional question for thought: How do `Foo(A)` and `Foo(B)` resolve (or fail to resolve) when `Foo(null)` is used as the invocation and both `A` and `B` directly extend `object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler resolves it at *compile time* by the type of *reference* of the parameter. For example:

```
Exception e = null;
Foo(e);
```

will be resolved to  Foo(Exception e), in contrasts:

```
Exception e = null;
Foo((object)e);
```

will be resolved to Foo(object o). Note that the type of the instance is not taken into account.

Comment: What about the case of `Foo(null)`? (e.g. [possible] ambiguity)

Comment: @Lukasz Bownik Is it now? ;-)

Comment: In that case, I think larsm's answer about "better conversion" is most accurate.

Comment: @Łukasz Bownik: How do your guess help?

Comment: Good answer on how nulls are being resolved. I think it's going to save me some future debugging time.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a constructor that takes an Animal and a constructor that takes an Insect. You pass it a value of compile-time type Butterfly.  Which one is called?

Insect. Both are valid, but the match from Butterfly to Insect is better than the match from Butterfly to Animal. Why? Because Insect is more specific than Animal. Every Insect is an Animal but some Animals are not Insects, so Insect must be more specific.

Same thing in your case. Exception is more specific than Object, so if you give an argument that matches both, Exception is chosen.

Make sense?

Answer (score 2):

The most relevant overload is selected - the one that is most derived and still fits the type passed in.

Since `Exception` derives from `Object`, it is chosen - a `null` could stand for either, so the `Exception` one is the one chosen.

I suggest reading the different articles by [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/overload+resolution/).

Comment: For being so concise this explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate of See [How does the compiler choose which method to call when a parameter type is ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696660/how-does-the-compiler-choose-which-method-to-call-when-a-parameter-type-is-ambigu).

From the accepted answer:

> It applies the "better conversion"
>   rules (7.4.3.3 of the C# 3 spec) as
>   part of overload resolution (section
>   7.4.3 in general).
>
> Basically in this case there's a
>   conversion from string to object, but
>   not from object to string. Following
>   the rules, that means the conversion
>   from null to string is better than the
>   one from null to object, so the
>   overload with the string parameter is
>   used.